# Redmine custom field display format

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

We have a Redmine installation with a custom field "Affected version" of type "version", where we display which version is affected by an issue (target version is the version where an issue is fixed). So the field displays the versions available to Redmine for a certain project.

However, for some projects, there can be quite a lot of versions. One in particular has over 400 possible versions to choose from.

Now, when the "Affected version" is displayed (i.e. when the issue is updated or created), the "Affected version" field is populated by all the versions available. The field itself it a 4 rows high HTML multi-select field.

As you can imagine, selecting 2 or 3 affected versions from 400 in a 4 row high HTML multi-select can be difficult.

Is there a way for us to alter how this field is displayed? We're not looking into altering the Redmine code, as this makes updates harder and more error prone. What we are looking for is maybe a plugin that allows HTML templates for custom fields, or any other functionality that would at least allow to change this defaulting to a 4 row selection list.

[image: This is how the field looks now]

Edit 1: I've thought about setting old versions to "Closed" or "Locked", as they shouldn't be displayed in version lists anymore. However, in custom fields of type version, they are still listed, even when locked/closed.

Comment: you can write plugin by yourself and override any template in redmine. In my case I just added new class to custom fields and make select2 jquery plugin to serve this class.

Comment: After all your questions I have one complex answer: find someone to perform onetime job customizing your redmine instance.

Comment: @Noma4i
Any easy way to make custom fields appear just after one specific field, like the issue's tracker ?  I tought I found a [working solution here](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/22918), but I'm completely noob at CSS, and have no idea how I could actually _move_ a field using that plug-in.